# What is creating generated.xml google_maps_key in Android Studio project?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to build the Android Google Maps sample app CurrentPlaceDetailsOnMap. However, the build keeps failing with a duplicate key error on google_maps_key. It's referenced in AndroidManifest.xml but it's defined in generated.xml. When I try to define it with my real maps key in either strings.xml or google_maps_api.xml I get get the duplicate key error. If I replace the reference in the manifest it gets overwritten with "YOUR API KEY HERE". I've never seen this before now. What's creating generated.xml?

Comment: If you select **MapActivity** at the beginning then it generates that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the solution. The google_maps_key resource string is generated in the Gradle scripts. Specifically by the resValue line in the build.gradle (Module: app) file under android, defaultConfig. The maps key must be added to the gradle.properties file.